# Sync AD Email to SharePoint 2007 Users

Tags: email, active-directory, sync

I have a AD that is populated to feed a SharePoit (SP) site, initial the AD did not have any email addresses in it, so when the users in SP were created the email was not present.

Now the emails have been added to the AD and I need them to copy over to SP so I can use the alerts etc in SP.

The Profile Synchronization is running in the ServiceJobDefinitions page, but I am quite confused about why this is not copying over.  I have read that users in SP have to be deleted and created again, this worries me, not knowing a huge amount about SP, I am always cautious about deleting anything.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to delete your users, at worst just the profiles.

The profile settings are managed in your Shared Service Provider, accessed from Central Admin.  Once in SSP, look for User Profiles and My sites area for links to manage profiles.

Microsoft posted a quick guide for troubleshooting issues like this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2388988

After going thru those posted items, if the problem persist please update with the actions you took, and the results of those actions.

Comment: Hi, have gone through the linked document and not much further, here are my findings: Database in marked as read-only in SQL Server - Not the case, all OK. Database status set to 'Offline' - All online and OK Site collection is set to read-only - Not the case, no locks in place. Profile Import is running - It is not running Content Database in in a moving state - It is not in a moving state User is not active in SharePoint - In the WSS_Content UserInfo table, the users are active.
Web App is excluded - None listed.

Thanks